# ajax is not returning response to view page

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, onclick

when I am debugging in firefox console window I can see the output but it's not coming on my viewpage , below I have mentioned my ajax code and my controller, I'm getting a result but view is not showing
Ajax:

```
<script>
$('.click').click(function(evt)
{
 evt.preventDefault();
 var link = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "{{url('/p_details?id')}}"+link,
   dataType: "json",
    data:{
       id:link
       },
  });

})
  .sucess(function(data)

   { 
      $('#property').empty('clear').html(row.html);
   }
     });
```

controller:

```
public function index()
{
       //$filter=Input::get('id');
       //var_dump($term);
        $view=DB::table('property_details')
     ->Where('sale_or_rent', '=', 'rent')
        ->orWhere('sale_or_rent', '=', 'sale')
       ->get();
     //  var_dump($view);
    return view::make('index', array('val'=>$view));
}

public function getPropertyDetails()
{
     $filter = Input::get('id');
    $display = DB::table('property_details')
              ->where('sale_or_rent', 'LIKE', '%' . $filter . '%')
              ->get();
              //var_dump($display); 

        if(count($display)!=0)
        {    
              $returnHTML = view('/pages/fliter')->with('val', $display)->render();
              return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
        }
        else
        {
            session::flash('status', 'No Records Found!!!');
            $returnHTML = view('/pages/fliter')->with('val', $display)->render();
            return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
        } 
  }
```

Comment: If you want to get the data from db to show it on the current page why don't you bring the whole data instead of just an URL.

And check that on $.ajax the param is "method" instead of "type" and if you are using jquery 1.8+ you should use .done() instead of .success() since it's deprecated and will be remove soon.

I think that once you have the ajax response you can $.parseJSON the data received and show it as you like. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: i m using instead of done()  method they only filter sale but the page should refresh of onclick.the link.

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you get the data you want from ajax?
The problem you have is server-side or client-side?

Comment: yes i'm getting the data  but when i click on anchor tag it's reloading to whole page, i do not want to reload my whole page, i want to filter the things on the basis of clicked category

Comment: Ok, so for what I understood, you have something like this <a href="#anchor1" id="a1">category_name</a> it shouldn't reload but if it doesn't check your function call has a whitespace before Default evt.**prevent Default**(); You have commented the window.location but if you are using it, that's what is causing the page refresh.

Is that so?

Comment: thaqs.....how to write the onclick to fliter but this ajax and url has been affected the homepage it refreshing when i am clicking anchor tag..\

Comment: Event does not bind with dynamically added element unless you delegate it to parent element or document using on()

Try $('.click').on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
...
...
}

Comment: <script>
                             $('.click').on('click',function(e){ 
                                  e.preventDefault(); 
                                  {
                                    evt.prevent Default();
         var link = $(this).attr('id');
         $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: 'p_details',
         dataType: "json",
        data:{
             id:link
            },
      });

          })
      .done(function(data)
              });  </script>     i can flow you but i m getting same result they should not fliter all the rent and sale...

Comment: This is how your js should look like, try to edit here (https://jsfiddle.net/9j3zdbet/), it's easier. So for your last comment it seems that the problem you now have is with the result that it's generated on your controller. It's a PHP problem. I need to know if the problem is in your query to the database or if it is to get the data to que ajax response?

Comment: thanks q....buddy i can try and tell my suggestion

Comment: i can follow  and suggest me i can do the changes in my code i am get html  view in the alert but  i am not get the view in my page.

Comment: It seems to me that you need to read more about laravel 5, you can start with this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-i-make-an-ajax-request-to-a-controller-method And I highly recommend you watching these videos https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals

Comment: typo in the callback: _.sucess(_ → _.success(_