# ajax is not returning response to view page in the application

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, onclick

when I am debugging in firefox console window I can see the output but it's not coming on my viewpage , below I have mentioned my ajax code and my controller, I'm getting a result but view is not showing

Ajax:

```
<script>
$('.click').click(function(evt) {
 evt.preventDefault();
 var link = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: 'p_details',
   dataType: "json",

   data: {
      id: link   
 }
});
   //alert(data);
}).done(function(data) { // pass the url back to the client after you    incremented it
$('#property').empty('clear').html(data.html);
});
 </script>
```

controller:

```
public function index()
{
       //$filter=Input::get('id');
       //var_dump($term);
        $view=DB::table('property_details')
     ->Where('sale_or_rent', '=', 'rent')
        ->orWhere('sale_or_rent', '=', 'sale')
       ->get();
     //  var_dump($view);
    return view::make('index', array('val'=>$view));
}

public function getPropertyDetails()
{
     $filter = Input::get('id');
    $display = DB::table('property_details')
              ->where('sale_or_rent', 'LIKE', '%' . $filter . '%')
              ->get();
              //var_dump($display); 

    if(count($display)!=0)
    {
        $returnHTML = view('/pages/fliter')->with('val', $display)->render();
        return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
    }
    else
    {
        session::flash('status', 'No Records Found!!!');
        $returnHTML = view('/pages/fliter')->with('val', $display)->render();
        return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ajax is not returning respones to view page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35908876/ajax-is-not-returning-respones-to-view-page)

Answer (score 0):

Should

```
$('#property').empty('clear').html(row.html);
```

not be

```
$('#property').empty('clear').html(data.html);
```

Also .sucess() is spelt wrong. It should be .success()

Comment: hi i have modified my code as per your suggestion but still it's not working , In my console I am getting the response...I have updated my ajax check above

Comment: @VallavanJ You've added your done function to after the click event. it needs to appear directly after the ajax function.

Comment: already .done function i have added after my ajax call ,, please elaborate more what you are saying..

Comment: You have written $('.click').click(function() {}).done() not $.ajax().done(). You should always properly indent your code. It helps stop mistakes like that.

Comment: u can suggest something i can implement on mycode but the view should not able to responance my page.in alert(html.data) i am seen html view but i m not getting the exact solution..plzz suggest something..

Comment: hello Thomas  when i am clicking on anchor tag i can see my html view but after 1 second my view is gone