# Ajax response is not coming on View Page

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, onclick

My ajax is working fine and I am trying to return ajax response on my view page but it's not returning anything but in alert i can see response generated by ajax so please suggest me how i can return ajax response to my page..

Ajax:

```
$('.click').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '\p_details?id'+link,
        dataType: "json",

        data: {
            id: link   
        }

    }).done(function(data) { 
        $('#property').html(data.html);
        alert(data.html);
    });

});
```

controller:

```
public function index()
{
    //$filter=Input::get('id');
    //var_dump($term);
    $view=DB::table('property_details')
        ->Where('sale_or_rent', '=', 'rent')
        ->orWhere('sale_or_rent', '=', 'sale')
        ->get();
    //  var_dump($view);
    return view::make('index', array('val'=>$view));
}

public function getPropertyDetails()
{
    $filter = Input::get('id');
    $display = DB::table('property_details')
        ->where('sale_or_rent', 'LIKE', '%' . $filter . '%')
        ->get();
    //var_dump($display); 

    if(count($display)!=0)
    {
        $returnHTML = view('/pages/fliter')->with('val', $display)->render();
        return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
    }
    else
    {
        session::flash('status', 'No Records Found!!!');
        $returnHTML = view('/pages/fliter')->with('val', $display)->render();
        return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
    } 
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block-content block-content-small-padding">
        <div class="block-content-inner">
            <h2 class="center">Recent Properties</h2>
            <ul class="properties-filter">
                <li class="selected"><a href="#" data-filter="*" ><span>All</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="{{URL::to('\p_details?id=featured')}}" id="featured" data-filter=".property-featured" class="click"><span>Featured</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ URL::to('\p_details?id=rent')}}" id="rent" data-filter=".property-rent" class="click"><span>Rent</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ URL::to('\p_details?id=sale')}}" id="sale" data-filter=".property-sale" class="click"><span>Sale</span></a></li>
            </ul>


            <div class="properties-items isotope" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 810px;">
                <div class="row property">
                    @foreach($val as $value)
                    <div class="property-item  col-sm-6 col-md-3 isotope-item " style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                        <div class="property-box">
                            <div class="property-box-inner">
                                <h3 class="property-box-title"><a href="#">{{$value->city}}</a></h3>
                                <h4 class="property-box-subtitle"><a href="#">{{$value->state}}</a></h4>
                                <div class="property-box-picture">
                                    <div class="property-box-price">{{$value->property_price}}</div>
                                    <div class="">
                                        <a href="#" class="property-box-picture-target">
                                            <img src="images/test/{{$value->image}}" alt="">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm afraid I don't understand your question. In your controller you seem to be returning some HTML, and in your JavaScript code you're `alert()`-ing that. So what exactly is unexpected? You can [edit] your question. Please try to write a problem description as clear as you can. Putting it in just a single line in the title is really not enough.

Comment: thanx for your reply i have edited my question please suggest something

Comment: What do you mean, "return ajax response"? The `alert(data.html)` is working, so do you mean that `$('#property').html(data.html)` isn't working? You typically don't "return" an ajax response. You make the ajax request, and when it finishes you do some action with a callback (this is what you're doing here with `.done(function(data) { ...}`).

Comment: so how can i return response to my viewpage , I have a div with id property so i am trying to return my response in that div    $('#property').html(data.html);

Comment: Yes, so `$('#property').html(data.html)` doesn't do anything? You don't see any changes in your page? That code looks correct, but I can't be sure, as I don't see the HTML page, or the contents of `data.html` ;-)

Comment: i have updated my html also ...please check

Comment: `#property` will get any element with `id="property"`, but I don't see that in your HTML. I *suspect* that you intend to replace this `<div>`: `<div class="row property">`? That has a **class** name, not an **id**! For classes, use `.property`. What's the difference, you may ask? A given `id` value may *only* occur once on a page, while a class may occur any number of times. So you can have only *one* element with `id="property"`, but may have any number of elements with `class="property".

Comment: i am change as per u r suggestion how can i return responance to my viewpage plzzz suggest i did't  get  exact solution....thanqssss

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ajax is not returning respones to view page in the application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917039/ajax-is-not-returning-respones-to-view-page-in-the-application)

Comment: on that time its not working fine but now i got the alert(data.html) view but it does not return in my view page.. i m change those things as per the sugesstion.plzzzz suggest something ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have write the sql query like this 2 foreach loop working fine.
I am not using any ajax call in this function.

```
Html   
            <div class="block-content-inner">
                    <h2 class="center">Recent Properties</h2>
                    <ul class="properties-filter">
                        <li class="selected"><a href="#" id="All" data-filter="*" class="click"><span>All</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="featured" data-filter=".property-featured" class="click"><span>Featured</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="rent" data-filter=".property-rent" class="click"><span>Rent</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="sale" data-filter=".property-sale" class="click "><span>Sale</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="properties-items isotope"  style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 810px;">
                        <div class="row ">
                            @foreach($rent as $value)
                                <div class="property-item property-rent  col-sm-6 col-md-3 isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                                    <div class="property-box">
                                        <div class="property-box-inner">
                                            <h3 class="property-box-title"><a href="#">{{$value->city}}</a></h3>
                                            <h4 class="property-box-subtitle"><a href="#">{{$value->state}}</a></h4>
                                            <div class="property-box-picture">
                                                <div class="property-box-price">{{$value->property_price}}</div>
                                                <div class="">
                                                    <a href="#" class="property-box-picture-target">
                                                        <img src="uploads/{{$value->image}}" alt="" style="width: 275px;height: 200px;">
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               @endforeach
                               @foreach($sale as $val)
                                <div class="property-item property-sale  col-sm-6 col-md-3 isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                                    <div class="property-box">
                                        <div class="property-box-inner">
                                            <h3 class="property-box-title"><a href="#">{{$val->city}}</a></h3>
                                            <h4 class="property-box-subtitle"><a href="#">{{$val->state}}</a></h4>
                                            <div class="property-box-picture">
                                                <div class="property-box-price">{{$val->property_price}}</div>
                                                <div class="">
                                                    <a href="#" class="property-box-picture-target">
                                                        <img src="uploads/{{$val->image}}" alt="" style="width: 275px;height: 200px;">
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               @endforeach




                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

sql query:

```
    public function index()
{


    $rent=DB::table('property_details')
    ->Where('sale_or_rent', '=', 'rent')
    ->take(8)
    ->get();

    $sale=DB::table('property_details')
    ->Where('sale_or_rent', '=', 'sale')
    ->take(8)
    ->get();


    $data=array('rent'=>$rent, 'sale'=>$sale);
    return View::make('index')->with($data);
}
```